# Order of Using Directives in C# - Alphabetically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

One short and simple question, but I can't find a solution:

'Is it possible to sort the using directives alphabetically?'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that a question about visual studio, if there's a function to short them? Then you should tell us which version you are using.

Comment: Yes, you use the "Sort using directives" menu option. (Under Edit, if I remember rightly.) If you've tried that but it hasn't worked, please give more details...

Comment: And where exactly did you try finding a solution? If you google your title (`"Order of Using Directives in C# - Alphabetically"`) then the first result (that is't this SO post) tells you the answer. Without looking I would assume the other results point to similar answers. Next time, when you ask a question like this, try saying "I can't be bothered to look properly" or "I can find the answer, but I want to increase my SO question count and maybe get some rep"

Comment: The [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) has an option that will remove and sort usings when you save a file.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Indeed, but who would search that with quotes anyway...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Why did you put quotes around your comment? Same reason I used them... my quotes were because I was quoting the title

Comment: Hint: if you need to sort your directives, you have too many of them. Either remove unused ones or reduce the code in the file.

Comment: @DavidArno: Or maybe it's just a case of OCD

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is. Just right click your directives, select [Organize Usings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514114.aspx) --> [Sort Usings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514113.aspx)

[image]

From documentation;

> There are two ways to call the operation:
>
> - Main Menu - On the Edit menu, point to IntelliSense, point to Organize Usings, and then click Sort Usings.
> - Context Menu - Right-click anywhere inside the code editor, point to Organize Usings, and then click Sort Usings.

**EDIT**: In **Visual Studio 2022**, the same option called as `Remove and Sort Usings` which you can also use `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+G` shortcut for that.

[image]

Comment: I don't find it. There is Intellisense but not "organize usings". I'm using the german IDE but there is nothing related to `using`.

Comment: I think it would be useful for the OP if you expand on your answer and explain how you found that documentation... perhaps you are some freak search wizard that knows some special tricks for finding things?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Weird. I use VS Ultimate 2012 as English IDE and [there is an option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ERNeF.png). Might be reason version (20xx) or Visual Studio edition (Ultimate, Enterprise, Express etc)? I honestly don't know why :/

Comment: @SonerGönül: 2012 Enterprise has it too, and I doubt it's special enough to not be included with express. It's just a simple sort after all. The docs suggest it is in all versions since 2008, and doesn't have any statements about it not being in specific editions only

Comment: @SonerGönül: now i have found it. If i right-click it is directly in the main menu quite at the top. No idea why it was not there from the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: For completness. The default is to place the System namespaces first while sorting. At least in some editions of VS. So its not 100% ~alphabetically~. Can be changed in the Options under Text Editor/C#/Advanced.(I see now its mentioned in the linked msdn docs)

Comment: @musefan I just know that feature of VS and searched on Google for docs :) I agree with you by the way. This is not a  _hidden_ feature at all. It should be exist in all versions and all editions of VS.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I wonder if perhaps using a different "development environment" has different context menus. I always used "C# environment", though I would expect VS to work out context menus based on file types anyway so...

Comment: @Ralf Indeed. As mentioned on doc; _By default, Visual Studio sorts using directives that begin with System before other using directives. You can modify Sort Usings to sort all using directives alphabetically_ And as you said, there is an option on _that_ options as: _Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings_.

Comment: @musefan Hmm, what you say is totally make sense to me. Maybe if you choose a different `development environment` when you installing your Visual Studio, this option might be invisible. Maybe that's why these documents are under the [Visual C# IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43f44291.aspx) page not `Visual Basic-Specific IntelliSense` or `JavaScript IntelliSense` pages.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this option in the settings of Visual Studio (Tools- Options etc.) and ReSharper

Comment: "Just right click your directives" where do you find these?

Comment: @seedee You can right click **inside** of the class (`.cs` file) and you can see this option. By the way, in `Visual Studio 2022`, looks like this option name changed as `Remove and Sort Usings` which you can also use `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+G` as a shortcut. https://imgur.com/a/d5PmdzQ

Answer (score 5):

go to Options, search for USING.  Select Advanced. Check box, "Place 'System' directives first when sorting using".

Now a click on the right click context menu, *Remove and Sort Usings*, will order the using statements 'correctly'.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

(C#) On Visual Studio 2017 code editor right-click menu, it is now named "Remove and Sort Usings", not nested in any command. And have CTRL+R, CTRL+G shortcut out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.
Context Menu - Right-click anywhere inside the code editor, point to Organize Usings, and then click Sort Usings.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514113.aspx